# ArcGIS for INSPIRE, build Protected sites Inspire layer

Tags: arcgis-10.1, inspire

Can anyone add some infomation about building protected sites inspire layer?
I cannot understand the whole specification schema and I didn't know how to use it in a real database.

Comment: Probably you are better off at a special INSPIRE interest group specific to either your country or your area of interest. The problem with the INSPIRE models is that they define a UML schema, which hat multiple mappings to relational databases. So there is not *the* way to use the schema in a database, but you'll have to derive the actual database tables on your own (please correct me where i am wrong).

Comment: @til_b: Thank the answer. Yes, I'm using this specification:
http://bit.ly/9RpioO
I'm trying to derive my attribute data with Inspire uml schema, but I don't know how to look. I found an example data on the net: http://www.filedropper.com/protectedsitesspagdbetrs89  This is the base shp with attribute. But in the UML scheme have a lot of relationship with other table in gdb xml tempplate. In this table contain some choice possibility f.e. Natura2000, but some of that I cannot chose my actual value (siteOfCommunityImportance).

Comment: http://www.filedropper.com/protectedsitesspagdbetrs89 deleted the second link, this is work

Comment: @til_b I think you should make your Comment into an Answer

Comment: I think you should edit your Question to include the additional details that you have provided as Comments.  It is the most detailed and clear Questions that tend to attract the quickest Answers.

Comment: @Polygeo will do.

Comment: Perhaps it would be best to ask this question on the INSPIRE thematic clusters forum this seems appropriate: [Who has implemented the Protected Sites Schema? and who has struggled?](https://themes.jrc.ec.europa.eu/discussion/view/10824/who-has-implemented-the-protected-sites-schema-and-who-has-struggled)

Comment: FME with the FME for INSPIRE plugin could help you a lot. But it's not cheap...

Answer (score 2):

Probably you are better off at a special INSPIRE interest group specific to either your country or your area of interest.

The problem with the INSPIRE models is that they define a UML schema, which has multiple mappings to relational databases. So there is not *the* way to use the schema in a database, but you'll have to derive the actual database tables on your own (please correct me where i am wrong).

Comment: I am trying to explain exactly what you described to my boss for several years now. so thumbs up